# Loss turns out to be nan in each epoch

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a model to distinguish 7 different emotions. I'm using the VGG16 model from keras. I've removed the last 'softmax' layer(from the initial architecture) and introduced my softmax layer with 7 classes. I've used RMSprop optimizer.
But, when fitting, the loss turns out to be nan in each epoch. I don't understand the error. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code snippet. (Assume I've imported all the required libraries)

```
model_use = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
model= Sequential()
for layer in model_use.layers:
    model.add(layer)
model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax', name='pred',kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))

#Now I imported the training and testing data into images, labels

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
datagen.fit(X_train)

model.compile(RMSprop(lr=1e-4),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32),verbose = 2 ,steps_per_epoch=int(len(X_train) / 32), epochs=10)
```

But the output comes out to be:

```
Epoch 1/10
 - 180s - loss: nan - acc: 0.1500
```

I ran the code till 10 epochs but the loss is still nan.